# setup vpnc to use vpnclient certificate for authentication

Tags: vpn, centos, authentication, ssl-certificate, vpnc

I am trying to access my company VPN using my Centos 5.5 laptop. I have the vpn client certificate issued by my company's IT dept. I am able to access the webmail using the same certificate which I installed in firefox. But I would like to know how to use this certificate to sign in to the VPN. Some of my colleagues use the Cisco VPN client v5.0.? software and the vpn client certificate to login. It works fine. But I would like to do the same with Centos.

I tried connecting using `vpnc`. I converted the `pcf` file to conf using `pcf2conf`. Converted the certificate to `.pem` file. I replaced the `/etc/vpnc/default.conf` file with the `pcf2conf` converted file. Following is the converted conf file:

```
IPSec gateway example-vpn.companyname.com
IPSec ID <groupid>
IPSec secret <groupsecret>

IKE Authmode psk
IKE DH Group dh2

CA-File /etc/vpnc/<certificate-file-name>.pem
Xauth username <employee-login-name>
```

When I tried to connect, I am getting `/usr/sbin/vpnc: authentication failed`. I am not sure whether the details of the certificate are being used. The reason I suspect this is, on the Cisco VPN client software you can chose between group username/passwd authentication (which prompts you for a PIN) and the vpn client certificate authentication. My colleagues select certificate authentication and they are able to login and are able to access their work stations via remote desktop.

When I searched on the internet on how to configure vpnc to use the certificate, some sources are pointing to [IPSec-tools](http://ipsec-tools.sourceforge.net/).

Has anyone setup vpn in your centos machine to access your company VPN using the vpnclient certificate authentication?

Looking forward to your replies. Thanks in advance for your time.

cheers.........

**EDIT:** Kindly move the question to Unix/Linux stackexchange (or any appropriate stackexchange) if this is not the appropriate place to ask this question. Thank you.